# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wordcloud'

Tags: python, python-3.x, wordcloud

Estou utilizando o `Microsoft Azure` com `Jupyter notebook` e preciso utilizar a nuvem de palavras.
Entretanto ao executar o código: `from wordcloud import WordCloud` ele apresenta o erro

> No module named 'wordcloud'

Vide Imagem: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Na raiz do projeto pelo terminal você roda os comandos que o usuário abaixo postou como resposta. `pip install wordcloud`. Tente rodar como administrador.

Comment: Tambem nao deu certo :/

Comment: Você verificou se as libs `pillow` e `numpy` estão instaladas? São dependências.

Comment: eu na verdade instalei elas

Comment: erro ao instalar o pillow.. 

Installing collected packages: pillow
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  ........... CONTINUA

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
........................ CONTINUA

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PIL'

Comment: Então, parece erro de permissão. Tente rodar com sudo ou se estiver usando windows, abrir o CMD com permissão de administrador.

Comment: Consegui reproduzir aqui, vou postar a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, na página da raiz do seu projeto, onde fica seu script em Python Clique em **Terminal** do lado direito.

[image: Lista de Projetos]

Depois digite `ls`. Assim como na imagem abaixo, pode ser que apareça algumas versões  **Anaconda**. Escolha a que você estiver usando e no mesmo lugar que você digitou `ls` digite `source anaconda3_501/bin/activate`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isso, na frente do seu usuário, no meu caso **nbuser**, vai aparecer **(base)**.

Agora sim faça o comando: `pip install wordcloud`. As dependências serão instaladas.

Depois que acabar, com a tela do terminal aberta, abra outra aba do navegador com o seu script em Python, e clique em `Kernel > Change Kernel...`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na telinha que abrir escolha o terminal que você está em sessão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Rode o script novamente e veja se funciona.

Comment: Não foi.. Obs: Acredito que possa ser porque você esta utilizando o JupyterLab e eu o Microsoft Azure. Não sei se pode ser por isso.. mas segue o erro.............................. Collecting wordcloud
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/b7/c16286efa3d442d6983b3842f982502c00306c1a4c719c41fb00d6017c77/wordcloud-1.5.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (357kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 358kB 320kB/s

Comment: Collecting pillow (from wordcloud)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8b/e9/5c47710fe383f0582da668302a80a6355fe15c2ce2dde89b50fe34acefa6/Pillow-5.4.1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.0MB 62kB/s
Collecting numpy>=1.6.1 (from wordcloud)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/15/690c13ae714e156491392cdbdbf41b485d23c285aa698239a67f7cfc9e0a/numpy-1.16.1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (17.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 17.2MB 5.8kB/s

Comment: Installing collected packages: pillow, numpy, wordcloud
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PIL'
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: O que você está utilizando exatamente? Versão do Python, Software...

Answer (score 0):

Tente

```
python -m pip install wordcloud
```

provavelmente vai precisar de `numpy` e `pillow` tambem

Se não funcionar outro problema podera ser que tem mais que 1 python instalado, o que fazer é

```
caminho/para/python -m pip install wordcloud
```

Pode tentar também

```
 !conda install wordcloud -y
```

Comment: Fiz isso, porém o erro permanece.

Comment: Alguma outra sugestão? Obs: Obrigada por tentar me ajudar :)

Comment: Fez no terminal do IDE ou no terminal do OS?

Comment: No terminal do IDE

Comment: Eu realmente não sei, todos os problemas de modules not found são pq não estão instalados, a última solução que tenho na manga é criar um environment novo, veja este exemplo em conda: conda create --name [nome] wordcloud

Comment: O que que é isso? :x "environment " ?

Comment: Eu não conheço o IDE que está usando porém deve ser algo de parecido

Comment: Environment é onde você escreve o codigo, é simplesmente criar um ficheiro novo só que eu forcei o wordcloud logo na criação